# When should my "Date of Formation" be for my LLC Company?

Tags: business

Please let me know if this should be posted somewhere else! Sorry if it isn't in the correct location!

#### Background

I am starting up a Web Development & Marketing Company in Ohio. I am not finished finalizing all of the small details, but plan to start taking client at the beginning of 2016. When filing for my LLC, what should I write down for my "Date of Formation"? I can only set it at a maximum of 90 days after filing. If I choose January 1st, 2016 is that going to work?

#### "Date of Formation" Idea?

- September 16th, 2015?
- December 15st, 2015? (To ensure the effective date is within 90 days.)
- December 31st, 2015?
- January 1st, 2016?

#### Forms

- [Limited Liability Company Certificate of
  Amendment](http://www.sos.state.oh.us/sos/upload/business/forms/543a.pdf).
- [Articles of Organization for a Domestic
  Limited Liability Company](http://www.sos.state.oh.us/sos/upload/business/forms/533a.pdf)

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

There's no requirement that you see clients immediately, but why not wait a few weeks to file so January 1st is within the 90-day period?